# Why am I not seeing any input on this server-client setup?

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

I'm trying to use socket.io for a work project. In order to learn how this library works, I want to setup a test server and client in which I can run some code.

For now, I have set up a working JavaScript server as per the example listed here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/.

```js
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server(3000);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

  console.log("connection");

  // send a message to the client
  socket.emit("hello from server", 1, "2", { 3: Buffer.from([4]) });

  // receive a message from the client
  socket.on("hello from client", (...args) => {
    console.log("client says hi");
  });
});
```

When I setup the client which is also shown on the website above, I see the output of my `console.log` function. Here's the working JavaScript client that I'm using:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000");

// send a message to the server
socket.emit("hello from client", 5, "6", { 7: Uint8Array.from([8]) });

// receive a message from the server
socket.on("hello from server", (...args) => {
  // ...
});
```

However, I need to run the client using Java. Here's my problem, and probably where I'm missing some fundamental insight, when I try to run a Java client with the above JavaScript server, I see no output whatsoever. I'm using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java and this is how I defined my client:

```java
// package + imports

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:3000");
        IO.Options options = IO.Options.builder().build();
        Socket socket = IO.socket(uri, options);

        socket.emit("hello from client", "world");
    }
}
```

I've also tried `URI uri = URI.create("ws://localhost:3000");` because the documentation says ws and http are interchangeable, but to no avail.

**Why is my server not outputting anything when I run my Java class, and how do fix it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `socket.open()` after `Socket socket = IO.socket(uri, options);` in my Java client.

I didn't see this posted in the documentation so I opened a PR to add it https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/pull/732